# Taxonomy term custom view page for all sub terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy called Sections and it has several terms,their children and grand children.
How can i set same display page or display format for all the sub section pages irrespective of their depth.

Comment: That sounds like standard behaviour... what have you tried and what did you end up with that isn't what you wanted?

Comment: Oops.. A lil mistake.! I want a custom display page. Like for example Tile, lead text and image alone for all the subsections pages. I tried those with the panels and views, but the result is  i need to go to each subsection pages and customize it. Its not applying in common.

Comment: Did you try creating a new variant for `/taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term`?

Comment: Yes Darvanen.I created a variant, assingned a layout, and in contents i assingned a view.But when i got to the subsection pages it remains the same.

Comment: The view is probably set with a contextual filter, that's where you need to go digging.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

This module will help you for sure :)

Read the documentation at https://www.drupal.org/node/577646

Comment: Good Documentation. It helped me:) Thanks Himanshu Pathak.